# What is the meaning of the resolution option of Adobe Reader

Tags: adobe-reader

In Adobe Reader preferences dialog under Page Display, there is an option "Resolution" with a default value 110 dpi. I tried to change it, from 56 to 400, and found nothing changed except zoom value. So what exactly is the purpose of this resolution option?

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with the resolution of a scanned document and the size at which it is displayed on your screen. For example, a common resolution to scan documents at is 300 DPI (dots per inch), so if you had this document on your computer and wanted to view it at it's original resolution, you would select 300 DPI.

As you figured out, all it really does is change the zoom level, but for some people (especially those that work with scanning or printing a lot) it can be an important tool to judge what a physical copy of something will look like. There's more to it than that, but it's the main idea.

For most people, however, it is not particularly useful, and unless you are doing more than viewing PDFs, you probably don't need to worry about it.

Comment: No, a PDF scanned document contains the actual dimensions of the picture. Then you don't have to set the "Acrobat resolution" to match the resolution of the scanned document.

Answer (score 0):

PDF files use different shapes with real dimensions (inches or points. Here, point means 1/72"). However, when displaying a PDF on the screen, it has to convert real dimensions to a number of pixels. And the ratio should depend of the resolution of your screen if you want the document to be shown without zooming effect.

If you set the resolution to match your screen resolution, the actual dimension of a document on screen will be the dimension of the document in the PDF file multiplied by the Acrobat Zoom, multiplied by the system Zoom.

Then with I have measured my screen 13.58" large, 1920 pixels, then 141 dpi (dots per inches), my system zoom is 125%. Then I have to set a 113dpi resolution (141/1.25) to make my documents on screen match their actual dimension. (With 100% Acrobat Reader zoom).